# Issues with singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I have created a single ton like this for ARC,

```
+ (MyClass *)sharedInstance {
    static MyClass *sharedSpeaker = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedSpeaker = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedSpeaker;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {

    }
    return self;
}
```

But here I am creating instances like this:

```
id speaker3 = [[MyClass alloc] init];
id speaker = [MyClass sharedInstance];
id speaker2 = [[MyClass alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Speaker 1= %@ \n speaker 2 = %@\n Speaker3 = %@",speaker,speaker2,speaker3);`
```

I got output as:

```
Speaker 1= <MyClass : 0xa45f5e0> 
speaker 2 = <MyClass : 0xa461740>
Speaker3 = <MyClass : 0xa4529e0>
```

This is looking like a desired behaviour. How to stop this when I am giving singleton in library to user. I need to block him from creating new instance. Do I need to make static global if I make it global he cant create the global variable of the same name there will be conflict right. So any memebers can give solution on this?

Comment: single ton doesn't need to initialize using init across the project, to access its instance you need to call its Class Method only. if you init it externally then it will return new instance all the time, if you want to create object then what the purpose of singleton??

Comment: Note that even if you disable init, you can't enforce singleton behavior in Objective-C because the user can always create more instances using `NSAllocateObject()` and `class_createInstance()`.

Comment: I dont know why I got a downgrade to this.. Actually a newcomer who is using my library can create an alloc init of my object... And If i use global variable and check it at the time of init methodfor object creation then global variable name conflict appears if someone wants to create the variable with the same name. I just wanted to check with the top people to get any good solutions for this... I dont know which brainy downgraded question...

Answer (score 3):

For example using an assert in the `init` method.

```
- (id)init {
    static int maxInstances = 1;

    assert(maxInstances > 0);

    maxInstances--;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Exceptions should be fatal.  This is overkill.

Comment: This is very simple. The `init` method will allow you to create only one instance. That means that if `sharedInstance` is created, no other instance can be created (through `init`). It's not a perfect solution but it's probably the best you can do.

Comment: Will u provide complete init method... still I dint understand I am sorry for that....

Answer (score 0):

Because you are creating new instances of your singleton class using `alloc`, `init`.

You will get the singleton instance using the **`sharedInstance` class method.** Like:

```
id speaker = [MyClass sharedInstance];
```

If you don't want to create the instances with `alloc` or `init`. Override those methods.

You can write `static MyClass *sharedSpeaker = nil;` as a static global variable and remove it from the `sharedInstance` method.

Comment: I told this in my question... Also I told that this variable blocks the developer in creating other variable in the same name... how to resolve that conflict....

Answer (score 0):

in .h file

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @interface Singleton : NSObject 
    {
            ///......
    }

    + (Singleton *)sharedSingleton;
```

in .m file

```
    #import "Singleton.h"

    @implementation Singleton
    static Singleton *singletonObj = NULL;

    + (Singleton *)sharedSingleton 
    {
            @synchronized(self) 
            {
                    if (singletonObj == NULL)
                            singletonObj = [[self alloc] init];
            }
            return(singletonObj);
    }
```

and use this in another file

```
    #import "Singleton.h"
    //.....

    Singleton *sinObj =  [Singleton sharedSingleton];   // not alloc and init. use direct
```

Comment: I did this... Wat if a new guy who doesn't know to use singleton did the Singleton alloc init??? I want to stop this also...

Answer (score 0):

```
create instance like this it will always return you singlton

static testSinglton *myinstance = nil;
+ (testSinglton *) sharedInstance {
    if (!myinstance) {
        myinstance = [[testSinglton alloc] init];
    }
    return myinstance;
}

- (id) init {

    if (myinstance) {
        return myinstance;
    }
    if (self = [super init]) {
        //new object now will be created...
        myinstance = self;
    }
    return self;
}

 NSLog(@"%@",[[testSinglton alloc] init]);
 NSLog(@"%@",[testSinglton sharedInstance]);
 NSLog(@"%@",[[testSinglton alloc] init]);
```

Comment: How to make this + (testSinglton *) sharedInstance thread safe.. What if two methids call this api same time in diff CPUs.. ???